# Am not able to run rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

The error that I get when I try to run this command is

```
Could not find gem 'json (>= 1.8.0) ruby', which is required by gem 'uglifier (>= 1.3.0) ruby', in any of the sources.
```

I have been looking around for a solution and what I've come across is people saying to just run  `bundle install` or `bundle update` but when I run `bundle install` or `bundle update` I get this error.

```
Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/bin/ruby -r ./siteconf20141122-37267-ceck48.rb extconf.rb 
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR=" clean

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
In file included from generator.c:1:
In file included from ./../fbuffer/fbuffer.h:5:
In file included from /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby.h:33:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.10.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Ruby.framework/Versions/2.0/usr/include/ruby-2.0.0/ruby/ruby.h:24:10: fatal error: 'ruby/config.h' file not found
#include "ruby/config.h"
     ^
1 error generated.
make: *** [generator.o] Error 1

make failed, exit code 2

Gem files will remain installed in /var/folders/n5/4jlbndy93t772cpgp3dr9znh0000gn/T/bundler20141122-37267-uyl5vv/json-1.8.1/gems/json-1.8.1 for inspection.
Results logged to /var/folders/n5/4jlbndy93t772cpgp3dr9znh0000gn/T/bundler20141122-37267-uyl5vv/json-1.8.1/extensions/universal-darwin-13/2.0.0/json-1.8.1/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing json (1.8.1), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.8.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I thought it might be helpful to point out that Im going through the one month rails trying to learn ruby on rails and don't know very much.

Comment: install ruby sources

Comment: Im sorry for being such a beginner but can you please explain?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mavericks [comes with ruby 2 preinstalled](https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/installation/#homebrew). Though you might tune the installation and install missing `ruby-dev`, I would **highly recommend** you to install ruby via [rvm](https://rvm.io/) (preferred) or [rbenv](https://github.com/sstephenson/rbenv) so you can manage multiple ruby versions and use gemsets.

Here is a good [step-through](http://chockfullweb.com/installing-ruby-mavericks) explanation on how to do this.

Comment: I was able to follow the instructions and everything came out fine in the end. Thank you so much I appreciate it

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this problem has to do with a recent update of XCode. After a XCode update you need to do the following steps:

1. Open Xcode and accept the license agreement
2. Reinstall the Command Line Tools.

The second step seems to depend on your OS versions. If `xcode-select --install` does not work try to start the `Install Command Line Developer Tools` app in `/System/Library/CoreServices`.

After reinstalling the Command Line Tools try to rerun `bundle install`.